# F# tuples into function parameters

Tags: parameters, f#, tuples, currying

Is there any way to convert tuple into separate parameters and put them to function instead of binding to variables?

Something like

```
let nice funOf5 tupleOf5 =
    funOf5 (Tuple.toParameters tupleOf5)
```

instead of

```
let ugly funOf5 tupleOf5 =
    let (number1, number2, number3, number4, number5) = tupleOf5
    funOf5 number1 number2 number3 number4 number5
```

Thanks.

Comment: for 2 or 3 member tuples you can use `<||` and `<|||`,https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.%5b-%5bhh-%5d%5b%27t1%2c%27t2%2c%27u%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d

Comment: @John Palmer Oh, thanks, I knew that arguments should be written as (arg1, arg2) for using pipes, but I did not  guess that it is also a tuple itself

Comment: Note, that it is `<||` not `<|`

Comment: Yes, by args quantity. But it is not work for more than 3 args?

Comment: no, the std lib only defines them for 3 args

Comment: @JohnPalmer link died, so here's another: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution, is to use pattern matching in the function definition.

This is inspired by the std lib solution for `|||>` which is

```
let inline (|||>) (x1,x2,x3) f = f x1 x2 x3
```

then you can have

```
let inline funof5 (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5) f = f x1 x2 x3 x4 x5
```